# Component vs before_Filter when considering session authorization?

Tags: session, cakephp

Which should I use component or before_Filter when using session to check authorization.

Comment: which version of cakephp are you using ? and would be good if you describe more.

Comment: cakephp 2.1.3 ver

Comment: I think you need to describe little more in questions..what exactly do yo want ? Do you mean authorization about roles and their access ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use isAuthorized for authorization.

[See the book](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what)

Specifically in your app controller you need to add this setting to your auth component
`'authorize' => array('Controller')`

and then do all your checks in the isAuthorized function. returning false from isAuthorized would not allow them to access the controller action and true would allow them access.

So example time.

Say you have the index action in the users controller and you only want an admin to have access to that action. In the isAuthorized function in the users controller you might check the user's session for the admin role.

```
function isAuthorized($user) {
    if ($this->action == 'index') {
        if ($user['role'] == 'admin') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```